I'm having trouble scraping a table from Baseball Reference
As the title suggests, I'm having trouble scraping a table from Baseball Reference. I want to scrape the first 2 tables from here. To be clear, the ones titled "Team Standard Batting" and "Team Standard Pitching" are the ones I want. I was able to extract the first table without a problem in R; my problem comes from trying to scrape the second one. Here is my exact code:
url2017 <- "https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/majors/2017.shtml"
webpage2017 <- read_html(url2017)

hitting_data2017 <- webpage2017 %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="div_teams_standard_batting"]') %>% 
  html_table()

hitterdata2017 <- hitting_data2017[[1]]

pitching_data2017 <- webpage2017 %>% 
  html_nodes('#teams_standard_pitching') %>% 
  html_table()

pitchingdata2017 <- pitching_data2017[[1]]

As I said before, the hitter data code works perfectly fine. However, the pitching data code, which is mostly the same, doesn't render any data.
Any help would be appreciated.

You'll have to excuse me as I primarily code in python and not R. But the reference.com pages will usually have the additional tables within the html comments. So you'll need to pull out those (or remove the comment tags in the html) to parse it.
try:
url2017 <- "https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/majors/2017.shtml"
webpage2017 <- read_html(url2017)

# Extract the HTML content as a string
html_content <- as.character(webpage2017)

# Remove all HTML comments
html_content_no_comments <- str_replace_all(html_content, "<!--|-->", "")

# Parse the cleaned HTML content
cleaned_html <- read_html(html_content_no_comments)

# Extract and parse the hitting data table from the cleaned HTML
hitting_data2017 <- cleaned_html %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="div_teams_standard_batting"]') %>% 
  html_table()

hitterdata2017 <- hitting_data2017[[1]]


# Extract and parse the pitching data table from the cleaned HTML
pitching_data2017 <- cleaned_html %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="div_teams_standard_pitching"]') %>% 
  html_table()

pitchingdata2017 <- pitching_data2017[[1]]


Unfortunately, I just get the same error. It doesn't give me a table to create.

Ok - let me have a go at it in R and see if I can debug it

Made a few edits @pcm1113. Can you try the new coe now?

That seems to have worked! What was your thought process and what did you end up changing?

1st (as stated) - the other tables were in the comments, so needed to remove those tags so it could parse the table. Then second html_nodes('#teams_standard_pitching') - theres is no id it was finding teams_standard_pitching, but rather div_teams_standard_pitching
